# Export Fluid Simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am currently abroad only with a Laptop.
I want to render a few simulations, my brother was so generous to offer his PC, he is several hundred miles away sadly.

What is the best way to export the simulation data so that he can render it for me? Its only 330MB, so that shouldnt be a problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The fluid sim stores its cache data in a separate file sequence, with the path specified on the domain object. You'll want to send your brother both your .blend file, and this cache sequence. He may need to adjust the path to the cache in the .blend file depending on where he places them.

Answer (score -1):

I think simply sending the .blend file to your brother and having him open it in blender and pressing the render button would work, although there may be a better way.